# como puedo hacer este problema e python con while

Tags: python, while

tengo un problema
el programa que estoy realizando debe de ejecutar una operación y después de dar el resultado preguntar si quiere realizar la operación o no (con una respuesta si o no) y ejecutarlo cuantas veces el usuario quiera o hasta que el usuario responda no.
pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

`##Para tributar un determinado impuesto se debe ser mayor de 16 años y tener unos ingresos iguales o superiores a 1000 € mensuales. Escribir un programa que pregunte al usuario su edad y sus ingresos mensuales y muestre por pantalla si el usuario tiene que tributar o no.
y que al final de la operación pregunte si o no para seguir ejecutando el texto o no.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
al final de la segunda pregunta no me hace la pregunta y me pide el valor sin hacer la pregunta..

```
edad=0      
ingM=0     

edad=int(input("ingrese su edad:"))
ingM=float(input("ingrese sus tributos mensuales: "))

if(edad>16)and(ingM>=1000):
  print("tiene que tributar")
else:
   print("no tiene que tributar")

v=input("desea ingreasar otro dato: ")   
while(v.lower()=='si'):
edad=int(input("ingrese su edad:"))
ingM=float(input("ingrese sus tributos mensuales: "))

if(edad>16)and(ingM>=1000):
    print("tiene que tributar")
if(edad>16)and(ingM<1000):
    print("no tiene que tributar")
if(edad<=16)and(ingM>=1000):
    print("no tiene que tributar")
if(edad<=16)and(ingM<1000):
    print("no tiene que tributar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Te puedes simplificar mucho código. En primer lugar no hace alta asignar el valor `0` a las variables `edad` y `ingM` pues después le asignaremos el valor real. Python es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico por lo que no debemos especificar el tipo de dato ni inicializar la variable con algún valor. También puedes ahorrarte algunos `input` si usas un `while True` (también puedes usar el operador morsa, pero no sé que versión de python utilizas)

```
while True:
    edad=int(input("ingrese su edad:"))
    ingM=float(input("ingrese sus tributos mensuales: "))
    
    if edad>=16 and ingM>=1000:
        print("Tiene que tributar")
    else:
        print("No tiene que tributar")

    if input("Desea ingresar otro dato?: ").lower() == "no":
        break
```

Esto repetirá el ciclo hasta que el usuario diga `no`, usamos la función `lower` para poder evitar *case sensitivity*. Luego también tendrías que usar un `try/except` para cuando el usuario ingrese su edad y los ingresos, pues el usuario puede ingresar `hola` en cualquiera de los 2 `input` y dará un error de conversión.